# Using integrated graphics in a dual monitor setup to improve FPS on the main monitor

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, performance, gaming

I am planning on buying a second monitor and while browsing for one, I began to wonder about a hypothetical (or not) scenario.
Besides my somewhat aging Radeon R9 290 I also have an integrated graphics card on my i5 4670K. Let's say instead of plugging both my monitors into my R9 290, I would let my IGC run my side monitor. Would this take some of the load off my discrete graphics card, thus allowing to squeeze out a few precious extra frames especially while gaming? Intuitively the answer seems to be a simple "yes", however I'm not sure about the practical impact:

1. Would the "saved" performance be significant enough to be noticeable?
2. Totally speculating, but are there perhaps some overhead costs for syncing between to graphics devices? Because if yes, hypothetically it could neglect any gains.
3. I realize that using IGC for my side monitor would make it much less performant, however I don't really plan on using it on anything above simple desktop work/text editing/having a browser open/wathcing a video. The IGC on 4670K should totally handle that, right?

Note that I am aware of [this question about performance impact of using integrated graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/1203618/dual-monitors-with-integrated-and-dedicated-graphics-card-performance-impacts) and it partially answers my practical concern #2, however my main focus is whether I would experience better performance on the monitor driven by my discrete graphics card, which the highest upvoted answer there, although very thorough, unfortunately does not really touch.

Any thoughts on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

From experience one problem you can find (that I had) is that having a different refresh rate on one monitor, for example 144Hz, can cause the refresh rate on the other monitor, operating at 60Hz, to be erratic and make video "juddery".

Playing a film or other streaming media on the second screen *can* be absolutely painful.

It seem that there is at least some evidence that [mixed refresh rate screens can cause issues on some graphics cards](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/5cj6u1/144hz60hz_dual_monitor_setup_game_stuttering/), I found it to be very aggravating on an Nvidia 1070. I do not know if this is still an issue on newer cards.

On the other hand plugging the second monitor in to the onboard graphics completely unlinks the two screens refresh rates and you get smooth playing video or games on both screens.

You can also free up resources on your "primary" card by using the hardware decoding capabilities of the onboard graphics. If you go to **Settings** -> **System** > **Display** > **Graphics settings** you can add programs and change their options to use the "Power saving" onboard graphics.

Basically you can assign programs that you are more likely to have on the second monitor, such as a video player, to use the onboard graphics and hence the onboard hardware decoding. I set Microsoft Edge, for streaming media, and a particular media player to use onboard graphics while the rest of my programs use the dedicated card.

If you move that program to the main monitor then the video will still be decoded by the onboard graphics, but will then be copied to the dedicated card over PCIe. Whether that is acceptable is up to you, but it is not too bad to change the setting back to dedicated and restart the application.

It may be using some amount of system resources, but it can be a more effective use of what you have, particularly if you don't mind setting it up a little.

I find it to be an acceptable use and while there may be a penalty it certainly is not completely killing framerates in games and I still get up to 100-144Hz in games that are using the dedicated graphics.

Most modern onboard graphics are more than enough for video playing and streaming media and general desktop duties so their performance can be 100% acceptable. That you can do it *and* free up some resource on your main card can actually make the system better.