# Is using both integrated and discrete graphics card effective? and if so how?

Tags: graphics-card, performance, gpu, integrated-graphics, discrete-graphics

I saw that on standby my GPU uses between 5-10% and with active zoom calls or videos it goes up to 25-30% (Which seems sensible but still a lot of bandwidth).
Now I know it is possible to use integrated and discrete graphics card on different monitors possible but I'm not sure if its worth the hassle and I would like some help deciding.

[image: GPU consumption image]

Questions:

1. Is using both GPU's effective?
2. If it is effective then how? *(Power efficiency, Gaming and Desktop performance, Temperature, etc.)*
3. Is there a way to use both monitors on both GPU's and automatically switch between them? *(Depends on the type of usage)*

My setup:

- CPU: Intel i5-10500 (6-core,3.1GHz).
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 (3GB).
- Motherboard: Gigabyte B460M.
- RAM memory: 2x Kingston HyperX (8GB,2666 MHz,DDR4)
- Internal Memory:

  1. WDC (1TB, HDD)
  2. SanDisk SSD PLUS (240GB).
- Power Supply: ASUS ROG (750W, Gold).

Comment: I use exactly this style of setup and have written about it https://superuser.com/questions/1611991/using-integrated-graphics-in-a-dual-monitor-setup-to-improve-fps-on-the-main-mon/1611996#1611996 and https://superuser.com/questions/1203618/dual-monitors-with-integrated-and-dedicated-graphics-card-performance-impacts/1203672#1203672 and more generally https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A19943+integrated

Comment: There are definitely  pros, in terms of unlinking the displays from each other, and making effective use of both GPUs, but there are downsides in having to set up applications to use a specific GPU, and some occasional "oddness" when using an application set up for one GPU on the screen connected to the other. 99% of the time though once you're set up it's fine and just works.

Comment: The only way I know to switch GPUs is via https://pureinfotech.com/set-gpu-app-windows-10/ or via a built in method if you laptop has it, but in either case it is per-application and needs to be done before the app runs otherwise you need to close and reopen it. Essentially I've set up "default" apps that I expect to use on the second screen (integrated) and always use them there. Using them on the main screen means data being copied over via PCIe which isn't a *big* problem for the few times I use them that way.