# Does it make sense to plug monitors in integrated graphics to "save" the GPU for other work?

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard, gpu

I have a GPU for the purposes of deep learning, and I have 3 monitors plugged into it. I also have 2 empty display slots in my motherboard. When I run a deep learning task my GPU shows as running at 100%, and small apps that rely on the GPU get performance issues (eg Xournal++ for writing notes with a stylus pad).

If I plug two of my monitors into the motherboard:

- Would that result in more capacity for the GPU to handle my deep learning tasks?
- Would it mean that if I use my small GPU dependent apps on the motherboard monitors, there wouldn't be performance issues?

Comment: See my comments on this similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1640455/is-using-both-integrated-and-discrete-graphics-card-effective-and-if-so-how#comment2506801_1640455

Comment: Thanks. That's useful and answers my question well enough